# Create Pandas DataFrame for use with ggPlot line plot

Tags: python, pandas, python-ggplot

I'm trying to create a Pandas dataFrame so that I can create some visualization with ggPlot. But I am having a hard time getting the DataFrame structure setup.

My visualization would be a line plot of (year vs. total). The line plot would be tracking multiple 'cause_of_death' over the years.

I have imported my CSV file, grouped by year, then 'cause_of_death' and do a count. But it is not in the right format to create a line plot because it is not a DataFrame.

Below is my code; any suggestion would be helpful,  thanks.

The field that I want from the CSV file are 'deathYear' and 'cause_of_death'

```
from pandas import * 
from ggplot import *

df = pandas.read_csv('query_result.csv')

newDF = df.loc[:,['date_of_death_year','acme_underlying_cause_code']]
data = DataFrame(newDF.groupby(['date_of_death_year','acme_underlying_cause_code']).size())

print data
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about what is currently happening with your code and the desired functionality that you're having issues with?

Answer (score 1):

This is a mega-old question, but it's pretty straightforward to solve. (*hint, it's nothing to do with `ggplot`. It's all about how `pandas` works*)

Here's how I'd render your code:

```
import numpy as np   # |Don't import * from these
import pandas as pd  # |
from ggplot import * # But this is customary because it's like R

# All this bit is just to make a DataFrame
# You can ignore it all
causes = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
years = [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004]
size = 100
data = {'causes':np.random.choice(causes, size),
        'years':np.random.choice(years, size),
        'something_else':np.random.random(size)
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Here's where the good stuff happens. You're importing from
# a CSV so you can just start here
counts = df.groupby(['years', 'causes'])['something_else'].count()
counts = counts.reset_index() # Because ggplot doesn't plot with indexes
g = ggplot(counts, aes(x='years', y='something_else', color='causes')) +\
        geom_line()
print(g)
```

Which results in:
[image: ggplot multi line plot]